# Elasticsearch emails' domain aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm new to Elasticsearch and I'm trying to count distinct occurrences of a field's substring.

I have e-mail recipients as part of a mail log index and I want to count amount of distinct domains in my index.

So for example, if there are 3 mail logs in my index and they come from the following addresses, `a@b.com`, `c@b.com` and `d@e.com`; I want to see **2 mails from `b.com` domain and 1 mail from `e.com` domain**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a [`pattern_capture` filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pattern-capture-tokenfilter.html) that should only capture what's after `@`. Also, not to mess with the original analysis of the text, I suggest adding a sub-field to the original `email` field and work with that only for this specific aggregation:

```
PUT /test
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "email_domains": {
          "type": "pattern_capture",
          "preserve_original" : 0,
          "patterns": [
            "@(.+)"
          ]
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "email": {
          "tokenizer": "uax_url_email",
          "filter": [
            "email_domains",
            "lowercase",
            "unique"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "emails": {
      "properties": {
        "email": {
          "type": "string",
          "fields": {
            "domain": {
              "type": "string",
              "analyzer": "email"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Trying out some test data:

```
POST /test/emails/_bulk
{"index":{"_id":"1"}}
{"email": "john.doe@gmail.com"}
{"index":{"_id":"2"}}
{"email": "john.doe@gmail.com, john.doe@outlook.com"}
{"index":{"_id":"3"}}
{"email": "hello-john.doe@outlook.com"}
{"index":{"_id":"4"}}
{"email": "john.doe@outlook.com"}
{"index":{"_id":"5"}}
{"email": "john@yahoo.com"}
```

And for your specific use case, a simple aggregation like the following should do it:

```
GET /test/emails/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "by_domain": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "email.domain",
        "size": 10
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And the result is like this:

```
   "aggregations": {
      "by_domain": {
         "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
         "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
         "buckets": [
            {
               "key": "outlook.com",
               "doc_count": 3
            },
            {
               "key": "gmail.com",
               "doc_count": 2
            },
            {
               "key": "yahoo.com",
               "doc_count": 1
            }
         ]
      }
   }
```